# How to transfer columns to rows in comma separated value file in python?

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I want to make columns as rows in csv file without using transpose of pandas. Here i have specified the columns in put them in specific arrays but i want loop to take the data dynamically. Also i want to print them as comma separated values in text file not in the shape of array.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to:

> i want loop to take the data dynamically

You can't transpose columns and rows without reading the whole csv file. I dont know if that is what you meant.

In order to transpose rows and columns, suppose that your file look like this one.

```
row1 col1,row1 col2,row1 col3
row2 col1,row2 col2,row2 col3
row3 col1,row3 col2,row3 col3
row4 col1,row4 col2,row4 col3
```

Then you can read the file in nested lists like this

```
>>> with open('file.csv') as f: rows_as_rows = [row[:-1].split(',') for row in f]
>>> print(rows_as_rows)
[
    ['row1 col1', 'row1 col2', 'row1 col3'],
    ['row2 col1', 'row2 col2', 'row2 col3'],
    ['row3 col1', 'row3 col2', 'row3 col3'],
    ['row4 col1', 'row4 col2', 'row4 col3']
]
```

Once all the rows are loaded you can transpose them. You can avoid using list, but the inner lists will be tuples instead

```
>>> cols_as_rows = [list(v) for v in [*zip(*rows_as_rows)]]
>>> print(cols_as_rows)
[
    ['row1 col1', 'row2 col1', 'row3 col1', 'row4 col1'],
    ['row1 col2', 'row2 col2', 'row3 col2', 'row4 col2'],
    ['row1 col3', 'row2 col3', 'row3 col3', 'row4 col3']
]
```

And you can format them to csv text with

```
>>> as_text = '\n'.join([','.join([v for v in col]) for col in cols_as_rows])
>>> print(as_text)
row1 col1,row2 col1,row3 col1,row4 col1
row1 col2,row2 col2,row3 col2,row4 col2
row1 col3,row2 col3,row3 col3,row4 col3
```

If you dont need to do any other thing with the data, you can also do this in a single line:

```
with open('file.csv') as f: print('\n'.join([','.join([v for v in col]) for col in [*zip(*[row[:-1].split(',') for row in f])]]))
```